# Obtaining a specific shape using nn.Conv2d

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Starting with an input shape like `(64, 1, 103, 8)` how should I set the parameters of `nn.Conv2d` to arrive at a shape of `(64, 32, 43, 8)`?

Currently I'm using the following

```
nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,out_channels=32, stride=(2,1),kernel_size=(3,3),padding=(0,1),dilation=(9,1))
```

But I'm afraid that `dilation` parameter may cause bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padding = (13, 1)`, `stride = (3, 1)` and `kernel_size = 3`:

```
nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, stride = (3, 1), padding = (13, 1))
```